# npm bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2, where is jquery, tether and popper?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm surprised to see the js removed from the bootstrap 4 beta 2 version. Why is that? Bootstrap 4 relies on jquery.js, tether.js and popper.js doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are now listed as [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/), which means that you'll need to install them separately.

Tether is **not** being used anymore, it got replaced by Popper.